# C memory mapped struct array leak

Tags: c, arrays, struct, shared-memory

I have two files, which I'm trying to IPC by shared memory. I allocate using similar statements in both files. In the server file:

```
int fd;
int size = MAX_LEN;
int bigSize = sizeof(struct region)+ size * sizeof(struct client_message) + size * sizeof(struct server_message);
    struct region *rptr = (struct region*)malloc(bigSize);
    printf("region size: %d clientMessage size: %d serverMessage size: %d and the total size: %d\n", sizeof(struct region), size * sizeof(struct client_message), size * sizeof(struct server_message), bigSize);
    fd = shm_open("/myregion", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

    if (ftruncate(fd, bigSize)  == -1)
        printf("error creating ftruncate\n");

    rptr = mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct region),
                PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

I've used the example on the following link to dynamically allocate shared memory:
[C Windows - Memory Mapped File - dynamic array within a shared struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731266/c-windows-memory-mapped-file-dynamic-array-within-a-shared-struct)

```
struct client_message {
    pthread_t client_id;
    int question;
};
struct server_message {
    pthread_t client_id;
    pid_t server_id;
    int answer;
};
struct region {        /* Defines "structure" of shared memory */
    int len;
    struct client_message ptr_client_message[0];
    struct server_message ptr_server_message[0];
};
```

when I assign in a while loop and increasing j in this server file,

```
(rptr->ptr_client_message[(j)%size]).question = 30;
(rptr->ptr_server_message[(j)%size]).answer = 20;
```

I read it from the client file as such:

```
printf("rptr len is %d and question of client %d is: %d, answer of server is %d \n", size, k%size, (rptr->ptr_client_message[(k)%size]).question, (rptr->ptr_server_message[(k)%size]).answer);
```

The outputs are mindboggling:
from the server terminal I get:

```
rptr len is 10 and question of client 0 is: 30, answer of server is 20 
rptr len is 10 and question of client 1 is: 30, answer of server is 20 
rptr len is 10 and question of client 2 is: 30, answer of server is 20 
...
```

changing for 10 elements of the client_message array, i.e. up to client [MAX_LEN]

from the client terminal I get:

```
rtpr len is 10 and question of client 0 is: 30, answer of server is 20
rptr len is 10 and question of client 1 is: 30, answer of server is 30
rptr len is 10 and question of client 2 is: 30, answer of server is 20
rptr len is 10 and question of client 3 is: 30, answer of server is 30
rptr len is 10 and question of client 4 is: 30, answer of server is 20
rptr len is 10 and question of client 5 is: 30, answer of server is 30
rptr len is 10 and question of client 6 is: 30, answer of server is 20
rptr len is 10 and question of client 7 is: 30, answer of server is 20
rptr len is 10 and question of client 8 is: 30, answer of server is 20
rptr len is 10 and question of client 9 is: 30, answer of server is 20
rptr len is 10 and question of client 0 is: 30, answer of server is 20
rptr len is 10 and question of client 1 is: 30, answer of server is 30
rptr len is 10 and question of client 2 is: 30, answer of server is 20
rptr len is 10 and question of client 3 is: 30, answer of server is 30
rptr len is 10 and question of client 4 is: 30, answer of server is 20
rptr len is 10 and question of client 5 is: 30, answer of server is 30
rptr len is 10 and question of client 6 is: 30, answer of server is 20
rptr len is 10 and question of client 7 is: 30, answer of server is 20
rptr len is 10 and question of client 8 is: 30, answer of server is 20
```

So, the entries in the struct region are mixed when reached from another process. How can I prevent this?

Comment: You cannot have 2 flexible array members in a struct. Basically `rptr->ptr_client_message` and `rptr->ptr_server_message` alias each other.

Comment: Thanks, any improvements you might recommend? By the way, how do you know it for sure, I mean any c references?

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p18: "As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a flexible array member."

Comment: Your compiler did not warn you about more than one flexible array in a struct? Did you crank up the warning level to maximum?

Comment: I'm new to unix and using sublime text 3, which didn't gave output so I've used gcc from the shell directly. Any plug-ins you can recommend?

Comment: Make a habit out of using `gcc -Wall`, and treat warnings as errors.

Comment: Also note that zero-length arrays are a [GNU C extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html), compared to flexible array members, and have slightly different semantics.

Comment: Well, considering they are alias of each other then my output should have been different but it works for 5 consecutive prints:           rptr len is 10 and question of client 6 is: 30, answer of server is 20
rptr len is 10 and question of client 7 is: 30, answer of server is 20
rptr len is 10 and question of client 8 is: 30, answer of server is 20
rptr len is 10 and question of client 9 is: 30, answer of server is 20
rptr len is 10 and question of client 0 is: 30, answer of server is 20

Comment: If I read your examples right, then your code breaks strict aliasing, so all bets are off and it is hard/pointless to reason about observed behaviour.

Comment: hmm `-Wall` doesn't catch this... strange :D Diagnostics provided with flexible array members (`[]`)` - *error: flexible array member not at end of struct*.

Comment: As you're using GCC and this is a GCC extension, I suggest you stop using the zero-sized arrays and use the C99-conforming `[]` flexible array members instead!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you can't use the [zero length array trick](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Zero-Length.html) twice in one struct.

The trick you're using in `struct region` is a GCC extension to allow you to have variable length arrays in a struct. The zero length array acts as a header, and then you can just remember that you tacked as much memory on the end as you like.

```
// This starts at rptr->client_message and advances two indexes.
rptr->client_message[2] = ...;
```

The problem is there's *another* zero length array immediately after `rptr->client_message`, `rptr->server_message`. So when you write to `rptr->client_message` you're overwriting `rptr->server_message`.

Let's simplify things and you'll see why.

```
struct region {
    int len;
    char ptr_client_message[0];
    char ptr_server_message[0];
};
```

Initialize it in the same way you do.

```
size_t size = 4;
struct region *rptr = malloc(sizeof(struct region) + size + size);
```

Now we seemingly have place for two 3 character strings. Let's add one.

```
rptr->ptr_server_message[0] = 'a';
rptr->ptr_server_message[1] = 'b';
rptr->ptr_server_message[2] = 'c';
rptr->ptr_server_message[3] = '\0';

printf("server_message: %s\n", rptr->ptr_server_message);
```

That's fine, it prints `abc`. Now let's populate `rptr->ptr_server_message`.

```
rptr->ptr_client_message[0] = '1';
rptr->ptr_client_message[1] = '2';
rptr->ptr_client_message[2] = '3';
rptr->ptr_client_message[3] = '\0';

printf("client_message: %s\n", rptr->ptr_client_message);
```

That's fine, it prints `123`. What about `rptr->ptr_server_message`?

```
printf("server_message: %s\n", rptr->ptr_server_message);
```

That prints `123` as well! It turns out they point at the same memory.

```
// 0x7ff5f1404144 0x7ff5f1404144
printf("%p, %p\n", rptr->ptr_client_message, rptr->ptr_server_message);
```

So, you can't have two zero length arrays in one struct.

Comment: Thanks, that was what ilja Everilä had said, but then why the procedure had worked for many consecutive points? it doesn't explain why did the procedure had worked for 5 consecutive points but mixed the results for client 1 client 3 and client 5

Comment: @b.g. Welcome to the Wonderful World of [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)! Plus multi-process shared memory which introduces all sorts of timing problems. Without seeing your code, I can't speculate on what might be happening, but it's moot because your code has already entered the realm of garbage in/garbage out. It's like driving a car blindfolded, swerving off the road, and wondering "Why did it take me *three* minutes before I crashed? Why not four? Or two?"